# Problem with Ubuntu 12.10 and hardware

Tags: 12.10, freeze

I have computer based on main board M4A785TD-M EVO. I am using graphics card from the main board.
My problem - Ubuntu freezes and it should be restared by either shutdown or by resent button. No key combinations work. No keyboard, no mouse - dead machine. And every time it freezes should be shutdown or reset it. After few times of shutting down or reset the machine cannot be booted. Not even e picture appeared on the screen. I carry it to the service shop but when we switched it on it starts without a problem. Ones computer was BIOS broken - may be with reason multiple shutdown. So I think problem appears only when computer works actively with software. 
Ubuntu is only OS on the computer so I haven't tested with Windows. I like Ubuntu and do not to switch to Windows. 
I have installed Nvidia drivers but not nvidia-173 (I have the option to install the former) since at the end of the process it informs it cannot find drivers for nvidia-173 and exits.

Could you please advice me if the problem is with graph card or anything else. I am willing to change the graph card but with what? Please advice me what graph card is the best for Ubuntu.

Please help me.

Kosta

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem? Try upgrading to a newer, supported, release. If you still have the same problem I suggest you ask a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem with my graphic card (ATI Radeon HD7650m). When i install ubuntu v 11.10/12.04/12.10, in software information i'm seeing the card as unknown device.

I tried update, all the steps I find on forums, tried to change the codes in driver of graphic but nothing...

So i install kubuntu and he find her immediately. i hope that help :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However my Ubuntu is finding the video card and installs the drivers (despite it cannot install additional updates of it). But still freezes. My card is ATI Radeon HD 4200. Do you had freezing of your installation of Ubuntu? Thank you.